# accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving children table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Connecting `users` and `companies` uses `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. When you add a user and save, the company information is not saved. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_role
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids, :company_attributes

  has_one :company, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles


  def role?(role_name)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role_name)
  end

  def with_company
    self.company.build
    self
  end

  private
    def create_role
      self.roles << Role.find_by_name(:user)  
    end
end
```

sign-up pages **new.html.haml**

```
    %div{:style => "margin:10px"}
      %h2= t('devise.shared.links.sign_up')
      %br
      = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
        = devise_error_messages!
        = f.fields_for :companies do |company_form|
          .control-group
            = company_form.label :name, :class => 'control-label'
            .controls
              = company_form.text_field :name
          .control-group
...
        .control-group
          = f.label :email, :class => 'control-label'
          .controls
            = f.text_field :email
        .control-group
          = f.label :password, :class => 'control-label'
          .controls
            = f.text_field :password
        .control-group
          = f.label :password_confirmation, :class => 'control-label'
          .controls
            = f.text_field :password_confirmation 
        .actions
          = f.submit t("Save"), :class => 'btn btn-primary'
          %br
          %br
          = render "links"
```

companies controller: https://gist.github.com/3863405

```
$rails --version
Rails 3.2.2

$ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: Can you post the output from inspecting the params, as they come into the controller?

Comment: output: https://gist.github.com/3863459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting stopped up by mass-assignment protection, despite having `attr_accessible :company_attributes` in your model...

Relevant log output:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: companies
```

Is that a direct copy/paste from your code, or is it possibly misspelled, or something, in the real code?

Comment: if change fields_for :company when not visible field on pag

Comment: Shucks. One last try - f.fields_for company_form :)

Comment: i chenge f.fields_for :company_form and WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: company_form

Comment: no, f.fields_for company_form (not the symbol, the actual object)

Comment: Brad thank for your help. i change f.fields_for :companies, self.companies.build, attr_accessible :companies_attributes, has_many :companies, accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies and work insert to companies table. bug appeared when I started to change the relationships between the tables

Answer (score 0):

add **:company_attributes** to attr_accessible in ur user model

add in User model

```
def build_company(params = {})
  self.company = Company.new(params)
end

def company_attributes=(attributes)
  self.company = Company.new(attributes)
end
```

Comment: :company_attributes already added, i changed to: companies_attributes but does not work